# Does it at all make sense to ask whether a factor analysis vs a network analysis better explains a dataset?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, latent-variable, social-network

I've read that these are philosophically different approaches in that a network analysis doesn't assume the existence of latent variables. Is it possible to submit the same dataset to both, and then ask which one is a better fit (i.e., whether latent variables are necessary to explain the data)?

In this data, x participants rated the same 40 items on 25 different scales. I'm interested in the relationships among the scales.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same question and I think the context is important to take into account. I found this article helpful: 'How to Compare Psychometric Factor and Network Models' by Kees-Jan Kan 1,* , Hannelies de Jonge 1, Han L. J. van der Maas 2, Stephen Z. Levine 3 and Sacha Epskamp.